# Secure OpenERP Server

Tags: networking, server, security, openerp

I use a Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop as a server 'only' for OpenERP 7.0. This OpenERP server is used by both, the team as well as clients. I've checked out posts that help someone secure a 'web-server' (i.e a LAPM one).

---

What I need is:

1. How to keep the system secure (from external threats and internal [don't tell me you haven't heard of nasty team-members who sabotage stuff when pissed off] too)?
2. How do I keep the OpenERP Server secure?
3. How to allow web-access to the OpenERP Server 'only' through a proxy & secure the route.
4. How to backup nightly to a NAS?
5. The server also 'transmits' data through another port (other than the OpenERP one). How do I add it to the proxy, etc too so that it can be accessed from the web (with or without auth)?
6. Would it be safe to use it as a print-server too? If yes, what should be the config?

---

I understand it's a very long one, I thought it'd be better to list everything at a single place.

P.S. If you insist, I'm ready to run distro-upgrade (to 13.04) via Terminal so that I don't lose any of my current data or settings.

Comment: Its alway a good idea to read official documentations in this case ;) [OpenERP Documentation v7.0](https://doc.openerp.com/) e.g [Security](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/04_security/)

Comment: @Achu Thanks for the comment, but OpenERP has a very pathetic documentation, which is often pretty vague. And before OpenERP, I wish to secure my system/OS for the purpose of using OpenERP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get a good sysadmin, that's the only way to protect from external and internal threat.
2. Paranoid talking: encrypt postgresql, use HTTPS, if possible use it in LAN only otherwise install gateway and use VPN only, use captive portal, upgrade to Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (then install the desktop on top of it), make sure all updates run automatically by cronjobs (all means ubuntu, openerp, postgresql, python, etc).
3. Captive portal, use pfsense or untangled gateway (until Ubuntu has its match)
4. Use cron, compress with bzip tar & copy entire openerp file and postgresql data.
5. No idea what proxy you're talking about, sorry.
6. yes. google: "cups security configuration"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I had done, incl the sysadmin part. A good way to put it, thanks.